# Error in RestSharp Request? , XML , The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, post, request, restsharp

> The `:` character , hexadecimal value `0x3A`, cannot be included in a name.

I get the above error from the API while parsing an XML body in a RestSharp `POST` Request.

What could I do?

```
  string xmlBody = "<soap:Envelope" +
                      " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                      " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                      " xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                      "<soap:Body> " +
                          "<MainField " +
                               " xmlns =\"http://www.w3.org\">" +
                               "<Username>string</Username> " +
                               "<Password>string</Password> " +
                               "<FieldPlace> " +
                                   "<Value1>string</Value1> " +
                                   "<Value2>string</Value2> " +  
                               "</FieldPlace> " +
                          "</MainField> " +
                      "</soap:Body> " +
                   "</soap:Envelope>";

  requestPost.AddParameter("text/xml", xmlBody, "text/xml" , ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

This is the XML

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <MainField>
              xmlns ="http://www.w3.org">
            <Username>string</Username>
            <Password>string</Password>
            <FieldPlace>
                <Value1>string</Value1>
                <Value2>string</Value2>
            </FieldPlace>
        </MainField>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the restRequest.AddXmlBody method?

Comment: This looks like invalid XML. It's declaring the `soap` namespace, but then trying to close elements in the undeclared `soap12` namespace. Also, `"URL"` is not a valid namespace string, I'm pretty sure.

You're also missing the XML declaration.

Comment: @gnud , I edited , I mistyped it

Comment: @RyanThomas, I have checked it its not working

Comment: You are building an invalid XML string. You get the same error without RestSharp, by just passing the XML string to `XDocument.Parse`. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/trw5j7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this corrected XML and let me know if that works for you.

Couple of points to note:

- 1. Missing spaces on the xmlns at the `soap:Envelope element`.
- 2. The `MainField` element was closed before adding the namespace.

```
string xmlBody = "<soap:Envelope" +
                 " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                 " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                 " xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                     "<soap:Body> " +
                         "<MainField " +
                              "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" > " +
                              "<Username>string</Username> " +
                              "<Password>string</Password> " +
                              "<FieldPlace> " +
                                  "<Value1>string</Value1> " +
                                  "<Value2>string</Value2> " +
                              "</FieldPlace> " +
                         "</MainField> " +
                     "</soap:Body> " +
                  "</soap:Envelope>";
```

I'd also recommend using an alternative method to generate the XML `string`, perhaps the `System.Xml.XmlWriter`.

Comment: It seems that it works !, Thank you, could you please tell me how to read and deserialize a Response of this Request?

Comment: What is the format of the response? XML also or JSON or something else? To read the response you can execute the request by using the Execute method on a RestClient object. var response = client.Execute(request) then response.Content will be the raw response.

Comment: The Response is XML . Like this.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <ResponseFields
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org">
   <Folder>
    <Field1>Value</Field1>
    <Field2>Value</Field2>
      <SubFolder>
        <Field3>Value</Field3>
        <Field4>Value</Field4>
       </SubFolder>
   </Folder>
  </ResponseFields>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: You can load that into an System.Xml.XmlDocument and use XPath to select specific node(s) or deseralize into an object using XmlSerializer object, there is documentation about this online as this is going off-topic of this question now.